# nested scope in python

Tags: python, lambda, scope

My question is regarding the rules of enclosing scope. In the snippet below if x=x is not passed to the header of F2 there will be an error

```
def f1():
    x = 88
    def f2(x=x): # Remember enclosing scope X with defaults
        print(x)
    f2()
f1()
```

however I dont understand why "x=x" is not needed in the lambda in the below snippet

```
def func():
   x = 4
   action = (lambda n: x ** n) # x remembered from enclosing def
   return action

x = func()
print(x(2))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Comment: I don't think that's a dup (although it's certainly related). Neither the question nor the accepted answer addresses the default parameter value hack at all.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you meant to post?

Answer (score 2):

> In the snippet below if x=x is not passed to the header of F2 there will be an error

No there won't:

```
>>> def f1():
...     x = 88
...     def f2():
...         print(x)
...     f2()
... 
>>> f1()
88
```

---

You only need the default parameter value hack when you're trying to pass a value that might get changed later. `f2` as I've written it captures the variable `x` from the enclosing scope, so it will print whatever `x` happens to be at the time. As you've written it, it captures the current value of the variable `x`, not the variable itself.

For example:

```
>>> def f1():
...     x = 88
...     def f2():
...         print(x)
...     x = 44
...     f2()
... 
>>> f1()
44

>>> def f1():
...     x = 88
...     def f2(x=x):
...         print(x)
...     x = 44
...     f2()
... 
>>> f1()
88
```

---

For a very common real-life example of where this difference is important, see [Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](https://docs.python.org/3.4/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result) in the official FAQ.